# How to access in javascript a json array created from php

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i have an array in php like this:

```
$arr['test'] = "asd";
$arr['test1'] = "asd1";
echo json_encode($arr);
```

and i get this using jquery post:

```
$.post("fillScheda.php",{scheda:num_scheda,id:idCliente},function(msg){

});
```

so in `msg` there is my json array... 
i tried to access in some way..

```
alert(msg[0].test);

alert(msg.test);
```

but result is always `undefined`... how can i access to values? can someone help me? thanks!!!

Comment: `msg.test` *should* work. Can you double check your server is outputting `{"test":"asd","test1":"asd1"}`, and nothing more via the network tab in your developer tools?

Comment: msg = eval('(' + msg + ')'); alert(msg.test);

Comment: @Matt i test using alert(msg) that the string resulted is the same you post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to parse the json object

```
msg = JSON.parse(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the type of return value of json:

```
$.post("fillScheda.php",{scheda:num_scheda,id:idCliente},function(msg){

},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serve json from the php file with this header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

So the code should be:

```
$arr['test'] = "asd";
$arr['test1'] = "asd1";

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```